# setInterval Meteor not working with mongodb update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Meteorjs and was fiddling around with it..

I set up the server to increment a variable in the mongodb collection each second.

```
// server code
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
  lists.update({name:"counter"},{$inc:{cnt:1}});
  GameObjects.find().forEach(function(u){
    iAmount = u;
    GameObjects.upsert({_id:u._id}, {$inc:{money:u.house}});
  });
}, 1000);
```

it works fine until i make the client increment some other value within the same mongo document

```
// client code
GameObjects.upsert({_id:GameObjects.findOne({owner:Meteor.userId()})['_id']}, {$inc:{house:1}});
```

so I was wondering why could this happen?

i can see that the setInterval function is still running (if i put a debug console.log in it it will still show something each second). but the update will no longer run.

any help or suggestions would be grateful

thank you

Comment: Do you use autopublish? When do you call that client code? Does `findOne` returns the correct value, or is the data not yet populated in time of the call?

Comment: @HubertOG I am currently using autopublish.. that like of client code is called when i click a button. findOne is always populated at the time of the call from the client.
[gist](https://gist.github.com/thinkong/8660392) this is the full code that i am working on